# Parse through multiple json responses to get the id value of each response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am making an AJAX call that receives multiple responses from the server in a json response. I want to get the `id` value of each response. Here is a sample of the response from the server:

```
{
 "success": true,
 "warnings": [],
 "errors": [],
 "requestId": "78098802gdu8",
 "result": [{ * * * "id": 1536 * * * , "name": "test\n ", "description": null, "createdAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "updatedAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "url": "https://some.name.com/"
 }]
```

I can get the `id` from a single response, but i am not having much success getting the `ids` from multiple responses, for instance:

```
{
"success": true,
"warnings": [],
"errors": [],
"requestId": "78098802gdu8",
"result": [
  { * * * "id": 1536 * * * , "name": "test\n ", "description": null, "createdAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "updatedAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "url": "https://some.name.com/"}] 
 {
  "success": true,
  "warnings": [],
  "errors": [],
  "requestId": "78098802gdu8",
   "result": [{ * * * "id": 1537 * * * , "name": "test\n ", "description": null, "createdAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "updatedAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "url": "//some.name.com/"}] 
   {
                "success": true,
                "warnings": [],
                "errors": [],
                "requestId": "78098802gdu8",
                "result": [{ * * * "id": 1538 * * * , "name": "test\n ", "description": null, "createdAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "updatedAt": "2015-09-23T18:44:46Z+0000", "url": "//some.name.com/"}]
   }
 }
```

}

Also, once I get the `ids`, i want to display them in a div. Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the code im using to get id from one response:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "somefile.php",
  data: {
    EmailName: Names,
    Type: EmailType
  },
  success: function (results) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(results);
    $('textarea').val(JSON.stringify(json.result[0].id));
  }
});
```

Comment: Im making an $.ajax call not API

Comment: Can you provide the code of your ajax call method?

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somefile.php",
    data:{EmailName: Names, Type: EmailType},
    success: function(results){
       var json = $.parseJSON(results);
      
  $('textarea' ).val(JSON.stringify(json.result[0].id));
         
        }
    });

Comment: Your "multiple responses" example contains invalid JSON. Is your server actually sending multiple response objects in one response? Or are you making multiple successive calls and expecting each response to update a list of IDs? If the former, your PHP file needs to return correct JSON. If the latter, your JS needs to *update* your textarea value, not overwrite your textarea value: ex. `$('textarea').val($('textarea').val() + ' ' + id);`

Comment: Yes im getting multiple responses. If i send a ajax request to dynamically create 10 things, the server sends a json response after each item has been created. So therefore i would get 10 json responses from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update your value, don't overwrite it on each callback

Here is a unit test showing how your success callback should update your `textarea` by appending the ids to the current value.

```js
/* FUNCTION THAT MAKES AJAX REQUEST */
function doAsyncThing() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somefile.php",
    // data: {…},
    success: function (results) {
      var json = $.parseJSON(results),
          id   = json.result[0].id,
          val  = $('textarea').val();
      $('textarea').val(val + ' ' + id);
    }
  });
}

/* BEGIN UNIT TEST */
// CREATE CLOSURE TO RETURN DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
function ajax_response(response) {
  return function (params) {
    params.success(response);
  };
}

var n = prompt("Number of AJAX calls to make", 10);

for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  
  // OVERRIDE $.ajax WITH DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
  $.ajax = ajax_response('{ "result": [{ "id": ' + i + ' }] }');
  doAsyncThing();
}
/* END UNIT TEST */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>IDs:</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry for just now getting back with you. I gave credit for this response because i believe we are halfway there. The only thing that isnt accurate here is the number of calls. Im only making one call, that will return multiple json responses from the server. Thats where im stuck at, but i believe  what you provided is part of the answer, but it still doesnt get each id from each response. here is an example response:
{"result":[{"id":1000}]} {"result":[{"id":1034}]}

how would i get both ids, from these two json responses?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I figured it out!

Comment: Before I answered, I commented asking for clarification about whether you were getting one response with multiple objects or multiple responses each with its own object. You answered: `Yes im getting multiple responses. If i send a ajax request to dynamically create 10 things, the server sends a json response after each item has been created. So therefore i would get 10 json responses from the server.` This answer addresses multiple responses from the server. But what I suspect you mean is that you get a single response with multiple objects. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually the answer you gave was very helpful, and correct. I do get a single response with many objects, and this is what i was attempting to do before, but i reworked it based on your example and now through using the for loop, i parse each json per loop, and it works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Reframe your question. You want to translate an array of one type - containing objects with one type of structure (containing an id) - into another - an array of only ids.

Then the answer is clear. The Javascript array type has the map operation which allows you to perform this translation. You only need to provide a function that can turn the structure containing the id into the id only.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map